# How to resolve "segmentation fault" on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I am a happy user of Raspbian on Raspberry Pi. I have some services there like VPN, Plex, Pi-Hole, etc.

Every 1-2 years it starts showing "segmentation fault", when running some commands. I need to take the card out, reflash it with a backup image and put it back in.

I know other people experience that too. Why is this happening? Is there something I can do to avoid it? Would mounting the SD card in r/o mode help?

Comment: It first happened after around half a year of usage. Then around 1 year and now around 2 years. So it looks like the problem occured from the beginning. I bought a good SD card, but maybe it was flawed. Do people run their RPIs for longer period of times (let's say 3-4 years) without this issue? I am also doing lots of r/w operations, but not on the SD card, but an external drive. Maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: I've got RPi1B that have been running NON-STOP for four or five years. SEGFAULT is a programming error, usually caused by going out of bounds on a data array.

Comment: Which commands in particular cause this ? Do you have logs (check in `/var/log`) ? An error message ? The question is just too broad and not enough details to provide meaningful guidance.

Comment: @tlfong01 *Segmentation fault usually means "could not find that memory segment" problem* -> This is **completely false**.  Please double check your meanings before asserting them here (that comment and the rest following from it have been deleted).

Comment: segfault: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: "Can't find" and "access violation" are not the same thing.  The first implies something has gone missing or been erased, which is false and misleading.  A seg fault is associated with a specific location in memory -- there is nothing that is missing.  The problem is that it is not allowed to perform a given operation on that location (read or write).  This occurs most commonly as a programming bug, when bounds are accidentally exceeded, etc.  It might also occur if an executable or library has become corrupted, which is a possible explanation in the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation faults can affect ANY operating system, although they should be a RARE event on a well managed system which repairs most damage automatically.

They are usually indicative of a damaged file system.

To refer specifically to the Pi they are more likely if you do not shutdown properly and/or use poor SD Cards. **SD Cards do wear out** with use, although the risk is greatly overstated, and many of us have been using the same for years without problems.

Fortunately there is a **simple UNIVERSAL solution** - perform regular backups.

The method of restoration varies with OS - the most common Pi method is to re-image the SD Card (or preferably a new SD Card) from you backup.